# Selecting exact value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck on a query and decided to ask for help here.
I have 2 tables **Students** and **Values**. In students I have the **Name** and in **Values** I have the grade.

Let's suppose we have 3 **students**.

```
**X** 7,8,10
**Y** 6,9,7
**Z** 7
```

How can i select the students with the grade EXACTLY "7"?
I tried:

**SELECT WHERE grade = 7** But it takes in the consideration the students who have "7" but also other grades too.

I think this problem is tricky, can someone give a hint?

Comment: So, you only want `Z` as a result?

Comment: So what are looking for? Students who have exactly one grade, and that grade is 7? Or students who may have one or more grades, but every grade is 7? Or students who may have one or more grades, and the average is 7?

Comment: Could a student have two `7`s?

Comment: yes, and i', stuck on this..

Comment: you should post `Students` and `Values` table schema.

Comment: yes, the student can have two 7's at different courses

Comment: And - what then? Should the student be included in result then?

Comment: In this case, I want to only get the result "Z". If you can tell me how to solve this problem, i think i can solve my other problem too..

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a comparison between unconditional and conditional counts:

```
select s.student_name
from   students s join grades g on s.student_id = g.student_id
group by student_id
having count(*) = count(case when g.value = 7 then 1 end)
;
```

(guessing at some column names along the way)

How it works: After joining the two tables, the rows are grouped by student_id. Then COUNT(*) counts all the grades, and the conditional count counts the grades equal to 7. The query returns the student names when the two counts are equal (meaning all the grades are 7).

Another solution (less efficient):

```
select s.student_name 
from   students s inner join grades g on s.student_id = g.student_id
where  g.grade = 7
minus
select s.student_name
from   students s inner join grades g on s.student_id = g.student_id
where  g.grade != 7 or g.grade is null
;
```

Comment: but this comment (after your post; or close to it) makes this a bit more challenging: "yes, the student can have two 7's at different courses" but not by much.

Comment: @xQbert - no, why? I find all the students who have only grades of 7 (no matter how many). COUNT(*) counts all the grades, the conditional COUNT() counts all the grades of 7, and they must be equal. Right?

Comment: I stand corrected! I missed the conditional aggregration

Comment: I didn't learn GROUP BY or HAVING until now. I must solve this question only with join..

Comment: @xQbert - OK, your question means others may have it too; it's better that I clarified the logic in my answer. Cheers!

Comment: @dimar: I assume you are serious. Who teaches joins before GROUP BY and HAVING?

Comment: The teacher started with WHERE,Oracle Functions and now left,right,full join :))

Comment: What did they teach for WHERE? Did they discuss set operations (UNION, MINUS)? Hard to answer this question with constraints on what may be used, if we don't know what the constraints are.

Comment: Yes, UNION, MINUS too. Now I think MINUS is a solution for this problem.. but don't realise

Comment: One solution with MINUS is easy: select all student names for student id with at least one grade of 7, MINUS select student names for student id with at least one grade different from 7 (or NULL).

Comment: This is much more complicated than any professor would assign - he must not understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to look at the task like this: Find students that have no grade other than seven.

```
select *
from students
where not exist
(
  select *
  from grades
  where grades.student_id = students.student_id
  and grades.grade <> 7
);
```

or

```
select *
from students
where student_id not in
(
  select student_id
  from grades
  where grade <> 7
);
```

Comment: There may be students with no grades at all (in which case they will be selected by these solutions), and also grade may be NULL so the condition has to be adapted to accommodate (unless we are told grade may not be null).

Comment: It worked for my problem, thank you ! Also @mathguy your solution with minus worked too.

Comment: But @mathguy is right. One would have to add an `EXISTS` or `IN` clause to make this work properly. To aggregate per student, as shown by mathguy, is the best way to this problem, only you said you were not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that an `INNER JOIN` followed by an exclusive `LEFT JOIN` would do the trick.  Something like this:

```
WITH

seven AS (
  SELECT a.id, a.name, b.grade
  FROM student_name a
  INNER JOIN student_grade b
  ON a.id = b.id
  WHERE b.grade = '7'
  )

, not_seven AS (
  SELECT a.id, a.name, a.grade
  FROM seven a
  LEFT JOIN student_grade
  ON a.id = b.id
  WHERE b.id IS NULL
  AND b.grade <> '7'
  )

SELECT * FROM not_seven;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using count and sum? Would that work?

```
   select s.student, Count(v.grade), sum(v.grade)
   From student as s 
        join values as v on v.student = s.student
   group by student
   having sum(v.grade) = 7 and count(v.grade) = 1
```

Comment: The OP instructed that they haven't learnt GROUP BY and HAVING yet (alas, in a comment to my answer instead of putting it in the Question). Also, this is looking for students who only got one grade, but the OP explained that a student who got two or three grades should be picked also, but only if all the grades were 7.

Comment: Also, please note that in Oracle, the keyword AS can be used for column aliases (optionally - you may use it but it is not required); but it may not be used for table aliases. So `students AS s` and `values AS v` will result in syntax errors.